# Sumar los datos iguales en SQL

Tags: sql, tsql

Tengo la siguiente tabla:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Estoy tratando de sumar TODOS los 3141.39, 8328.43, etc para tener una suma de cuanto son, estoy intentando algo asi:

```
SELECT DISTINCT(cod_parte), SUM(cantidad)
FROM dbo.Det_materiales 
WHERE factura='1885'
GROUP BY cantidad, cod_parte
```

Pero mi resultado es este:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Por que no suma la totalidad, si son iguales y como puedo resolverlo?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

No suma porque estás agrupando también por el valor `cantidad`. Además en tu caso, no necesitas usar `DISTINCT`

```
SELECT cod_parte, SUM(cantidad) Cantidad
FROM dbo.Det_materials
WHERE factura='1885'
GROUP BY cod_parte
;
```